# Ros stereo image proc with two USB Webcams

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow the tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc
I am trying to connect two USB Webcams and  do stereo image processing aand looking to obtain the point cloud by this tutorial.
Each time I do rostopic list, it does NOT show me the following :
/stereo/left/image_raw
/stereo/left/camera_info
/stereo/right/image_raw
/stereo/right/camera_info

I was wondering that whether it can be used with two webcams or not or is it not meant for that and only recognizes the stereo cameras.

It would be great if anyone helps, I have been stuck on this for about few weeks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236474/ros-stereo-image-proc-with-two-usb-webcams/) by [goelshivam1210](https://answers.ros.org/users/27108/goelshivam1210/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you should look at this package : http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam

It will allow you to have a camera topic in output.

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0